# Is there a network config TUI that supports HTTP proxies?

Tags: linux, networking, http, proxy

I am building a headless Linux appliance. Some of its users will be running it in an environment that requires an HTTP proxy. I was thinking of having NetworkManager-tui running perpetually on TTY2 for most of the networking config, but this utility has no facility for configuring an HTTP/HTTPS proxy. Are there any plugins for NetworkManager or perhaps another ncurses-like utility that I can make available to the user for setting this?

I know its not that hard to set the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables for the environment, but my users are not going to be smart enough to follow instructions and do this correctly.